# JQuery : Setting a dropdownlist to readonly until data is finished loading

Tags: jquery

Hey, is it possible to set an Html.dropdownlist to readonly (or not selectable) until some data is finished loading? I have several dropdownlists that are dependent on each other and with web apps not being as fast as a regular app, i want to do this so the user doesnt get too confused when data dissapears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the dropdown lists by calling

```
$('select').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Bang on! Just had to figure out where to put this. Thanks!